# DIV following mouse position goes crazy

Tags: jquery

in my homeworks I'm trying to animate a div, moving it trying to follow mouse last position. Well, my DIV just goes crazy over the viewport. It's like he is adding values and not just moving to them. Can you take a look at my code to enlighten me? Thank you. P.s. Ufo have absolute position 0,0.

```
var ufo = $('#ufo');
var posX;
var posY;


$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

posX = e.pageX;
posY = e.pageY;

});

window.setInterval(function() {

ufo.animate({
    top: posX,
    left: posY
}, '1000');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UFO is choppily moving to a new position every 3 seconds, right?  I think you want to ditch the animation and `setInterval` and just do this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    ufo.css('left', e.offsetX || e.layerX || e.pageX); 
    ufo.css('top', e.offsetY || e.layerY || e.pageY);
});
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution. If the mouse position was being "added" each time, the UFO div would quickly disappear from the viewport altogether.

Comment: Well, actually my UFO moves to really strange positions. I'm logging e.pageX and Y and both are right. But even if they are, say(200,200), my DIV goes to other positions. I wonder if there's something wrong in my code.

Comment: oh... I was looking just at the fact that you did it directly in the mousemove, and wasn't paying attention to the code! haha

Comment: @AndrewBarber can you please explain why in my code (as you right guessed) mouse position is Added and not replaced?

Comment: `ufo.css('left', e.offsetX || e.layerX || e.pageX);`
`ufo.css('top', e.offsetY || e.layerY || e.pageY);`

Comment: @Daniele - I think the problem was that you were only changing the position of the div every 3 seconds, and then animating it.  The code above should move it in real time

Comment: Oh inverted dlrow ...     

    top: posX, -> top: posY
    left: posY -> left: posX